# Concatenate Rows with Group By Clause in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, concatenation

Below is the SQL query. And the output I am getting from it. I have provided the desired output. Please help what is that I am doing wrong.

```
select drp.vendorid,drp.GuaranteeType,drp.Guarantee_Enable,drp.Advance_Required,rtypes=stuff(
(select distinct '~' + rate_plan_type_id from ds_rate_plan drp2 where drp2.rate_plan_id = drp.rate_plan_id for xml path('')),1,1,'')
from ds_rate_plan drp
where drp.vendorid in ('00072211','00000004','00000001')
group by vendorid,drp.GuaranteeType,drp.Guarantee_Enable,drp.Advance_Required,drp.rate_plan_id
```

Below is the output I am getting:
[image]

Below is the desired output:

```
00000001    PrePay   false   false   B2C~CPT~FPH~MOR
```

EDIT (As Requested):
The table and the desired output. Can you guys help now?
[image]

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You didnt provide sample data. But based on your output you need only `GROUP BY vendorid`

Answer (score 0):

Your correlation clause should be on `vendorid`, not `rate_plan_type_id`:

```
select drp.vendorid, drp.GuaranteeType, drp.Guarantee_Enable, drp.Advance_Required,
       stuff( (select distinct '~' + drp2.rate_plan_type_id
               from ds_rate_plan drp2
               where drp2.vendorid = drp.vendorid
               for xml path('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as rtypes
from (select distinct drp.vendorid, drp.GuaranteeType, drp.Guarantee_Enable, drp.Advance_Required
      from ds_rate_plan drp
      where drp.vendorid in ('00072211', '00000004', '00000001')
     ) drp
```

Comment: This does give me my desired output but the data is not correct. Because the correlation clause on vendorid is not unique. I used rate_plan_id because it is unique. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you could try below way

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (vendorid int,rtype NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @temp (vendorid,rtype)
VALUES (1,'B2C'),(1,'B2C'),(1,'B2C'),(1,'CPT');


with cte as
(
select distinct * from @temp
) select distinct vendorid,STUFF((
        SELECT ',' +  rtype
        FROM cte t1
        where t1.vendorid = t2.vendorid
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS Places from cte t2
```